# Going around in circles with Pure Virtual Functions

Tags: c++

I am using a simple inheritance structure to try and simplify code structure and reduce common code usage across a number of classes.

The idea is to allow a simple linked list structure within the class to allow the entire set of instances to be iterated.

EDIT:

To elaborate, this is intended to support a bunch of classes that can be aggregated by type and then iterated by type. Hence the decision to use a linked list with a static "first member" held in the class.

The actual application is support classes for switches, buttons, lights, parsers inside an embedded platform (Arduino).

When I create 20 switch instances of cSwitch (for instance)

```
    cSwitch cSwitchA(_pin,callback);
    cSwitch cSwitchB(_pin,callback);
```

I can then use

```
    loop() {
       cSwitch::checkAll();
    }
```

inside my "loop" function, rather than having to do:

```
    void loop() {
       cSwitchA::check();
       cSwitchB::check();
       ...
    }
...
```

extending this to other classes, I can do:

```
    loop() {
       cSwitch::checkAll();
       cLight::checkAll();
       cParser::checkAll();
     }
```

all of the members are declared with pins, parameters and callback functions.

I think that the problem is not specific to Arduino, but a little more abstract in that it could probably arise in any similar scenario.

```
class cGroup {

   public:
      cGroup(){cGroup::register_instance(this);}
      ~cGroup();

      static void register_instance(cGroup * _inst) {

          cGroup pInstance=nullptr;

          if (_inst->getFirstInstance()==nullptr) {
             _inst->setFirstInstance(_inst);
             return;
          } else {
             pInstance=_inst->getFirstInstance();
          }


          while (1) {
              if (pInstance->getNextInstance() == nullptr) {
                 pInstance->setNextInstance(_inst);
                 return;
              } else {
                 pInstance=_inst->getNextInstance();
              }
          }
      }

      static void checkAll(cGroup * firstInstance);

      virtual cGroup* getFirstInstance()=0;
      virtual void setFirstInstance(cGroup*)=0;


};

class cMemberA: public cGroup {

   public:

      cMemberA():cGroup(){}
      static void checkAll() {cGroup::checkAll(cMemberA::firstInstance);}

      static cGroup * _firstInstance;

      cGroup* getFirstInstance() {return cMemberA::firstInstance;}
      void setFirstInstance(cGroup* _firstInstance){cMemberA::firstInstance = _firstInstance;}

};

cGroup * cMemberA::_firstInstance = nullptr;

class cMemberB: public cGroup {
... etc
};
```

The main need to do it this way stems from the fact that if I push the static "firstInstance" variable up into the cGroup class, it only allows for one long list containing many different types of Member classes. What I want is one list per type of Member class, meaning that I need to scope the static "firstInstance" variable into the Member class itself.

The problem I am finding is that I am going around in circles trying to figure out how to invoke getFirstInstance() and setFirstInstance from within the member class while only having a cGroup* pointer to play with.

If I have pure virtual classes inside of cGroup with cGroup * declarations, then these are not satisfied by declarations in the subclass of cMemberA * (and cMemberB *, cMemberC etc...)

declaring the "first-instance" members as "cMemberA*" leads to compilation issues (abstract class), but declaring them as cGroup* leads to an inability to invoke the required members in the cMemberA instances.

Is there another way to do this, or am I fundamentally going about this the wrong way? Please be gentle, it's been about 10 years since my last rodeo with C++ and I'm not a professional programmer.

Of course I can get around this issue by dispensing with cGroup entirely and just putting everything into cMemberA, cMemberB etc. but then that's where I was last week and as far as I recall, that's not the best way with C++ as the whole idea is to reduce code duplication.

Comment: First question: Why roll your own linked list when things like [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) exist?

Comment: embedded scenario that doesnt support STL.

Comment: Can you back up a little and tell us about the problem you're trying to solve with this machinery?

Comment: All the linkage needs to be in `cGroup`, not in each subclass. The linkage is common to all subclasses, as per your description. As such, the pointers will be all `cGroup` pointers, and all that the subclass provides is the instance of the class itself. P.S. The shown code will have pretty bad performance, each instance of the (sub)class will require an additional iteration to find the end of the list. The list should consist of a head/tail pointers, and adding a new instance will always take the same time, and not require finding the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik Agree that performance can be improved, but I will work on that once I have got this fundamental merry-go-round sorted. The problem with putting everything into cGroup is that it only creates one list, and I need one list per subclass type, so I need to scope the static "firstInstance" member to each of the subclasses.

Comment: Have your subclass return the pointer to the list that's used for that particular subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted does have a problem, but I think it's different from the ones you mentioned.

The problem I see is that you call `register_instance` from the cGroup constructor, and then call virtual functions, eg. `getFirstInstance()` from that. Virtual calls don't work as expected at construction time (because the vtable isn't properly initialized yet). Basically you need to construct your object first, and you can call `register` once the object is fully constructed, in a second step.

The usual way around this would be to use a factory function instead of directly the constructors. The factory function would first create a new instance, then register that fully created instance, then return it. BUT, your factory function would need to create the instance on heap and return a pointer (if it returned by value, then it would register an instance, return a copy of it, then destruct the registered instance). Usually this isn't a problem, types with virtual functions are usually used as reference types (not value types) anyway, but in your particular embedded case that may be a problem.

Another way is to create intermediate classes between cGroup and cMemberX, eg. `cMemberA: cMemberABase: cGroup`. `first_instance` and `getFirstIntsnace()` etc. would be defined in `cMemberABase`. Then cMemberA's constructor could call `cGroup::register`, because by that time the vtable for `cMemberABase` is already constructed (but not yet for `cMemberA`!). In other words, when in the subclass constructor, the base subobject's virtuals can already be used, but not the virtuals defined in the subclass.

```
class cGroup {
protected:
    cGroup(){}

public:
    template <class G> static G* make() {
        G* instance = new G();
        cGroup::register_instance(instance);
        return instance;
    }

    ~cGroup() {}

    static void register_instance(cGroup * _inst) {

        cGroup* pInstance=nullptr;

        if (_inst->getFirstInstance()==nullptr) {
            _inst->setFirstInstance(_inst);
            return;
        } else {
            pInstance=_inst->getFirstInstance();
        }


        while (1) {
            if (pInstance->getNextInstance() == nullptr) {
                pInstance->setNextInstance(_inst);
                return;
            } else {
                pInstance=_inst->getNextInstance();
            }
        }
    }

    static void checkAll(cGroup * firstInstance) {
    }

    virtual cGroup* getFirstInstance()=0;
    virtual void setFirstInstance(cGroup*)=0;

    cGroup* getNextInstance() { return nextInstance; }
    void setNextInstance(cGroup* nextInstance) { this->nextInstance = nextInstance; }
    cGroup* nextInstance = nullptr;
};

class cMemberABase: public cGroup {
protected:
    friend class cGroup;
    cMemberABase():cGroup(){}

public:
   static void checkAll() {cGroup::checkAll(cMemberABase::firstInstance);}

   static cGroup * firstInstance;

   cGroup* getFirstInstance() {return cMemberABase::firstInstance;}
   void setFirstInstance(cGroup* _firstInstance){cMemberABase::firstInstance = _firstInstance;}
};
cGroup* cMemberABase::firstInstance = nullptr;

class cMemberBBase: public cGroup {
protected:
    friend class cGroup;
    cMemberBBase():cGroup(){}

public:
   static void checkAll() {cGroup::checkAll(cMemberBBase::firstInstance);}

   static cGroup * firstInstance;

   cGroup* getFirstInstance() {return cMemberBBase::firstInstance;}
   void setFirstInstance(cGroup* _firstInstance){cMemberBBase::firstInstance = _firstInstance;}
};
cGroup* cMemberBBase::firstInstance = nullptr;


class cMemberA: cMemberABase {
public:
    cMemberA(): cMemberABase() {
        cGroup::register_instance(this);
    }
};

class cMemberB: cMemberBBase {
public:
    cMemberB(): cMemberBBase() {
        cGroup::register_instance(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Understanding of the issues around vtable initialisation was key to solving this one. I went with a static "make" function in the member class definition due to the multiple constructor styles in use. That was a simple solution to the problem - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler and idiomatic to let the outer code organize objects into containers as needed:

```
cSwitch cSwitches[2] = {{_pin,callback}, {_pin,callback}};

loop() {
    for (auto& switch : cSwitches)
        switch.check();
}
```

If you want "names" for the elements, add an enum:

```
enum cSwitchNames { A, B, count };
cSwitches[A].check(); // if you need to check just one
```

Comment: Unfortunately for the audience this is being developed for, this is not going to be simple enough, and also the compiler doesn't support the "auto" keyword. I understand that there are other ways of doing this, but part of my reason for asking the question is so that I can learn what I was doing wrong in my original approach.

Comment: You can replace `auto` easily enough, even if that means you have to use a template function instead of the for loop.  As for simplicity, well, I feel this is way simpler than static member linked lists, but I guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Mark The Arduino IDE supports `auto` variables for a long time (since about 1.6.5), and compiler was supporting it even before this version, it was just disabled. So you have to use something quite outdated.